# Determinant of a matrix defined by $a_{i+i,j+1}=a_{i,j}+a_{i+1,j}+a_{i,j+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, determinant

Let $A_n$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with entries defined by $a_{i+i,j+1}=a_{i,j}+a_{i+1,j}+a_{i,j+1}$ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n-1$ and $a_{1,j}=a_{i,1}=1$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

What is $\det(A_n)$?

Example:

$$A_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 5 \\
1 & 5 & 13
\end{bmatrix}$$

Initial values: $\det(A_1)=1$, $\det(A_2)=2$ and $\det(A_3)=8$.

Maybe it is $$\det(A_n)=2^{n(n-1)/2}$$ but it is just a guess idk.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you calculate the initial values and make a guess?

Comment: You can also try using Gessel Viennot lemma. Should not be hard because the array is the same that for the proof that $det \left(\binom{i+j}{i}\right ) =1.$

Comment: @Phicar Could you link this lemma or a proof of $\det \left(\binom{i+j}{i}\right ) =1$ using it?

Comment: @JPMarciano I will later today. I am busy now, but I will outline the lemma and a proof for your identity. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: @Phicar No problem. Whenever you can :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** As is suggested by the setup, perform row/column reductions by subtracting each row from the row above it (starting at the bottom).

**Hint:** Read the previous hint $n$ times (with a suitable modification to make things easy).

What do you end up with?

> You end up with a upper triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are $ 2^{i-1}$.
>  Hence, the determinant is $ 2^ { n(n-1) / 2}$ as you hypothesized.

---

Note: I currently don't have a simple explanation for the diagonal entries. The best that I can come up with is

> The generating function for the $i$th row is $ \frac{ (1+x)^{i-1} } { (1 - x)^i }$, and so when you take the successive difference, you end up with $2^{i-1}$.

Comment: @JPMarciano Note that this isn't a complete solution. For example, I've not provided any justification for values of the diagonal entries.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find a simpler way than your note either. Thank you very much for your answer!